# Maximize Variable value based on set of columns

Tags: r, regression, maximize

I have a data set with some columns(All factors), I want to maximize the Sum of column "Value_to_Dollar_Finance". For this I need to find the combination of various other columns and their levels which maximizes "Value_to_Dollar_Finance".
I can find the combination of levels if i explicitly fix the columns as:

```
data_prep
dt <-data.table(data_prep[,-1])
setkeyv(dt,c("Age","Gender"))
dt[,sum(Value_to_Dollar_Finance),by=key(dt)]
```

In this i have fixed the columns to "Age"and "Gender" and so i get this output:

```
       Age Gender   V1
 1: 18 to 24 Female 3914
 2: 18 to 24   Male 1648
 3: 25 to 34 Female 5356
 4: 25 to 34   Male 5356
 5: 35 to 44 Female 2266
 6: 35 to 44   Male 2060
 7: 45 to 54 Female 5562
 8: 45 to 54   Male 1236
 9: 55 to 64 Female  206
10: 55 to 64   Male  412
11:      65+   Male 1030
```

Sorting which i can say Age-:45 to 54 and Gender:Female maximizes my variable "Value_to_Dollar_Finance".
I wanted to know how can i figure out which all columns( let say will adding HHI_Income to the Key increase "Value_to_Dollar_Finance")  to use to maximize "Value_to_Dollar_Finance".

Here is the dput of the dataset:

```
structure(list(user_id_64 = c(9.07342e+17, 4.63301e+18, 1.25057e+18, 
3.7687e+17, 4.38708e+18, 6.06174e+18, 6.56232e+18, 3.7804e+18, 
7.20452e+18, 8.0051e+18, 8.65669e+17, 8.4059e+18, 6.26951e+18, 
1.04779e+18, 3.79093e+18, 4.55963e+18, 5.54535e+18, 2.8122e+18, 
8.56233e+18, 7.29827e+17, 7.94754e+18, 2.15311e+17, 8.10245e+18, 
8.39761e+18, 7.82216e+18, 1.74928e+18, 8.88483e+17, 7.31851e+18, 
1.83674e+18, 5.31255e+18, 8.12717e+18, 4.89047e+17, 6.85394e+18, 
3.93333e+18, 1.10588e+18, 1.17008e+18, 4.20943e+18, 5.79288e+18, 
1.71195e+18, 8.37821e+18, 3.31628e+18, 3.1075e+18, 1.43078e+18, 
8.78603e+18, 4.69163e+18, 7.30254e+18, 6.21261e+18, 2.27262e+18, 
6.02168e+18, 3.49317e+18, 3.16143e+18, 1.61317e+18, 6.08074e+18, 
8.50853e+18, 7.6479e+18, 8.13491e+18, 7.32427e+18, 8.02574e+18, 
6.93734e+18, 4.81579e+17, 1.25689e+18, 1.26517e+18, 3.33812e+18, 
4.12716e+18, 2.31695e+18, 3.77893e+18, 8.32529e+18, 7.89111e+18, 
6.30124e+17, 5.84101e+17, 8.94783e+18, 7.88774e+18, 2.30005e+17, 
1.6935e+18, 4.66029e+18, 4.63604e+17, 4.18723e+18, 9.07208e+18, 
7.5426e+18, 4.41737e+18, 4.61709e+18, 5.87117e+18, 5.24036e+18, 
6.57733e+18, 7.16735e+18, 3.2182e+18, 2.7689e+17, 3.42698e+18, 
1.35236e+18, 6.62158e+17, 4.3897e+18, 2.8965e+18, 3.54381e+18, 
4.67134e+18, 6.08533e+18, 4.74586e+18, 6.33812e+18, 3.17199e+18
), Age = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("", "18 to 24", "25 to 34", 
"35 to 44", "45 to 54", "55 to 64", "65+"), class = "factor"), 
    Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), Relationship_Status = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("", "In a Relationship", 
    "Married", "Single"), class = "factor"), HHI_Income = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "£10k-£15k", 
    "£15-£20k", "£20-£25k", "£30-£40k", "£40-£50k", "£50-£75k", 
    "£75k+", "Under £10k"), class = "factor"), Value_to_Dollar_Finance = c(206L, 
    412L, 618L, 206L, 824L, 412L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 
    206L, 824L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 
    206L, 206L, 206L, 412L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 412L, 206L, 206L, 
    824L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 412L, 618L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 
    206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 412L, 206L, 618L, 
    412L, 824L, 206L, 824L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 
    206L, 412L, 206L, 206L, 412L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 1030L, 206L, 
    412L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 824L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 412L, 
    206L, 206L, 206L, 412L, 412L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 
    206L, 206L, 412L, 206L, 206L, 412L, 206L)), .Names = c("user_id_64", 
"Age", "Gender", "Relationship_Status", "HHI_Income", "Value_to_Dollar_Finance"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(30L, 31L, 39L, 43L, 69L, 
86L, 118L, 143L, 169L, 183L, 195L, 196L, 236L, 247L, 259L, 279L, 
304L, 313L, 347L, 359L, 461L, 472L, 525L, 585L, 705L, 887L, 910L, 
920L, 931L, 946L, 1003L, 1010L, 1016L, 1019L, 1026L, 1030L, 1032L, 
1040L, 1050L, 1105L, 1159L, 1174L, 1179L, 1257L, 1259L, 1268L, 
1286L, 1302L, 1376L, 1458L, 1762L, 1874L, 1989L, 2116L, 2123L, 
2129L, 2137L, 2138L, 2144L, 2179L, 2193L, 2225L, 2471L, 2522L, 
2548L, 2595L, 2596L, 2788L, 2796L, 2797L, 2855L, 2926L, 2938L, 
2984L, 3015L, 3050L, 3055L, 3065L, 3068L, 3073L, 3075L, 3078L, 
3082L, 3084L, 3085L, 3101L, 3103L, 3105L, 3114L, 3122L, 3140L, 
3157L, 3206L, 3244L, 3273L, 3384L, 3395L, 3405L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you would like to see (e.g. only the combination that maximises "Value_to_Dollar_Finance" based on the classifications), you could go with the following solution:

```
require(data.table)
dt <-data.table(data_prep[,-1])
setkeyv(dt,c("Age","Gender","HHI_Income"))
data.aggregated <- dt[,sum(Value_to_Dollar_Finance),by=key(dt)]
data.aggregated[which(data.aggregated$V1==max(data.aggregated$V1)),]

#         Age Gender HHI_Income   V1
# 1: 25 to 34 Female  £10k-£15k 2060
```

Hope that's what you are looking for.

EDIT:

Or in case you want to know which combinations give which maximum value, you can go for the "brute force" solution

```
require(data.table)
dt <-data.table(data_prep[,-1])

variables <- c("Age","Gender","Relationship_Status","HHI_Income")
combinations <- apply(X=as.matrix(1:length(variables)),MARGIN=1,FUN=function(X){combn(x=variables,m=X)})
for(i in 1:length(combinations)){for(j in 1:dim(combinations[[i]])[2]){setkeyv(dt,combinations[[i]][,j]) ; data.aggregated <- dt[,sum(Value_to_Dollar_Finance),by=key(dt)] ; print(combinations[[i]][,j]) ; print(data.aggregated[which(data.aggregated$V1==max(data.aggregated$V1)),])}}
```

and then compare the outputs.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my questions to some extent although via brute force. I was wondering if there was some other technique as well, just to be informed.

Comment: Unless you have a clear idea about which variables might provide the optimal solution, you basically have to explore all combinations. In case you think my answer fits your needs, think about accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simplier approach -- why not use regression to help you?

You can regress all factors on the variable of interest and interpret the coefficients to maximize the outcome:

```
require(data.table)
dt <-data.table(data_prep[,-1])
setkeyv(dt,c("Age","Gender"))
dt[,sum(Value_to_Dollar_Finance),by=key(dt)]

glm(Value_to_Dollar_Finance~. , data = dt)
```

This tells that to maximize the outcome I'd choose:

- Age of `18 to 24`
- Gender of `Female`
- Relationship_Status of `Single`
- HHI_Income of `£30-£40k`

Comment: Yes this would work, but as this would suggest me the individual levels which maximizes the dependent variable for each variable that goes into regression, how can I figure out which all independent variables to plug into the regression,  you used all, what if we could have maximized using just 3.

Comment: @PSraj Good question. You can fit alternative specifications of the model and send each regression to a model object `mod <-` and then use `predict` to compare which regression gives the highest predicted value.